# Creating a feed from a list of links in yahoo pipes

Tags: rss, pipe, yahoo-pipes

I was trying to get a custom RSS feed to use with the MiroTV app - an application that gets video from an RSS feed and download it so you can watch it in your pc. I mostly use MiroTV to watch video lectures from sites that already a nice rss feed for their lectures like Yale Open Courses.

I learned about Yahoo! Pipes recently and I wanted to try to do a pipe that parses a page with a list of links to lecture videos into a RSS feed. But I really couldn't understand the interface. My experience with web programming is zero and I really hate involved graphical programming interfaces (I feel MUCH more confortable editing real code than connecting little arrows).

So my questions are:

1 - how can I create a pipe that will read, i.e., this page:

http://www.physics.harvard.edu/about/Phys253.html

and cach all the links to FLV files and create a RSS feed with those links.

2 - Is there a CLI-like interface to really code a pipe? A python API or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the fetch page module and parse the relevant links. [Sample pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=1qoLq6ai3BGv06982R2EvQ).
2. No, but take a look at [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/). You can also extend pipes functionality with the Web Service module ([sample pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=KAMnPi5F3BGdNiMxouNLYQ))